# FieldSet element in ASP.net

Tags: html, css

I am using FieldSet element in my web application. Now I need to apply style to it so that the border color is blue and the legend is bold in color.
How do i do that? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this -

```
<style>
.hdrText
{
    color:red;
font-weight:bold;
}
.border
{
border: solid 1px blue;
}
</style>
<fieldset class="border"><legend class="hdrText">header</legend></fieldset>
```